# How to set z-index of dropdown div

Tags: css, reactjs

**Problem:**

I am trying to create a dropdown. When input is focused, the div below it appears. But I expect the div to be at higher z-index. If the div is at higher z-index, then button below it will be covered, but right now div does not take any z-index.

**Code:**

I have this example on which I am working now:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(    <div style={{width: 200}}>
    <input className="input" />
    <div className="dropdown" style={{ position: 'absolute', zIndex: 9999 }}></div>
    <button>Hello</button>
  </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Main></Main>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

Here is CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  background: #333;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
}

input + div.dropdown {
    background-color: #ffff00;
    display: none;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}

input:focus + div.dropdown {
    display: flex;
}
```

Here is the plunker of the same code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/B8Kjhv6rUOv0s7QKotxI?p=preview

**What I tried:**

If I change the position of dropdown div to absolute, then z-index is applied, but the width of the div is equal to the screen width.

I am creating a reusable component, so I can't give fixed width.

**Note:**

Fixed width given to main div is just an example but in actual use case, the width of main div will be automatically determined by the 100% width of its parent component.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Sorry, I pasted in the wrong link:  Here it is https://plnkr.co/edit/wjmKoLg4D3Qfd9TlKlm4?p=preview

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError don't know why this happened, but I will fix it and reply you in two minutes.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Can you please now check this? https://plnkr.co/edit/B8Kjhv6rUOv0s7QKotxI?p=preview

Comment: I can reproduce the issue now. Just to clarify, do you want the dropdown to remain at `width` it is when *not* positioned `absolute`?

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError I just want the dropdown's width = its parent's width, which will actually be computed to available space in real project

Comment: Declare `position: relative` on that containing element. To demonstrate this in your plunker sandbox environment, declare this rule to the containing (parent) `div` element of the `input`, `.dropdown` and `button`. Probably better to attribute a class selector to this element as well so that you can manage and maintain these styles externally with other declared styles (in `style.css`).

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Thanks man. Thats working. That wasn't tricky at all, but I need to learn more about position. Can you please post it as answer?, so that I can accept it

Comment: Would be happy to, allow me a few minutes and I'll have one posted.

Comment: Roger that. will wait...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Summary:**

Declare `position relative` on the containing (parent) element to allow a measure of control over *absolutely positioned* sibling element's `width`.

**About positioned elements and stacking context:**

A few things to consider when dealing with *positioned* elements and *stacking context*:

- `z-index` property values will only apply to *positioned* elements.
- *positioned* elements are elements with `position` property values defined as `absolute`, `fixed`, `relative` or
  `sticky`<sup>[experimental](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky)</sup>; this does not include `static`,
  the default positioning of any element.
- When declaring an element as an *absolutely positioned* element
  (`absolute` or `fixed`) you are *removing the element from the
  natural document flow*; which simply means the element is no longer
  interacting with sibling elements in the way `relative` or `static`
  elements do (imagine the element "siting above" the rest of the DOM).
- By default, an *absolutely positioned* element's position is
  "relative" to the *window*; this means if you offset its position
  with `left` or `right` property values it'll move a distance equal to
  the property value *from the window*. You can position an element
  with a `position` property value of `absolute` (not `fixed`) relative
  to any containing element *if you declare relative positioning to
  that containing element*.
- This was the issue you were observing in your use-case; since the
  nested `.dropdown` element was positioned `absolute` it was taken out
  of the natural flow and occupied the full available width of the
  containing document, so in order to restrict it to the width of its
  containing element, `position: relative` should be declared on its
  containing element, e.g:

  `<div style="width:200px;position: relative;" data-reactid=".0">
     <input class="input" data-reactid=".0.0">
     <div class="dropdown" style="position:absolute;z-index:9999;" data-reactid=".0.1"></div>
     <button data-reactid=".0.2">Hello</button>
  </div>`

It would probably be better (and more scallable) to attribute a class selector to this element as well so that you can manage and maintain these styles externally with other declared styles (in style.css), e.g:

**Amended `html` structure:**

```
<div class="foobar" data-reactid=".0">
   <input class="input" data-reactid=".0.0">
   <div class="dropdown" style="position:absolute;z-index:9999;" data-reactid=".0.1"></div>
   <button data-reactid=".0.2">Hello</button>
</div>
```

**Additional `css` declarations:**

```
.foobar {
   width:200px;
   position: relative; /* required for nested absolute element */
}
```

**Reference:**

1. [position - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky)
2. [z-index - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation in great detail.

Comment: It was a pleasure, really. There is method behind the madness of `position` properties but the concept is actually easy to grasp, and once you do, it's difficult forget it again.